# Strapi afterCreate hook doesn't show relation data when triggered from REST API

Tags: rest, strapi

I have a table with 1 relation like in this picture :

[Request table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQbtK.png)

**ISSUE :**
My current issue is when i add a new data from the REST API. Somehow, if i add the data from Strapi admin page, i can see the relation data (in this case, Country) at afterCreate hook's result. But if i add the data through the REST API, it doesn't show the relation data.

**WHAT I GOT :**
Here are the parameters i received from beforeCreate hook, when i add through Strapi's admin page:

```
{
  first_name: 'John',
  last_name: 'from strapi local',
  phone_number: '123456',
  email: 'member@email.test',
  number_of_property_managed: '3',
  country: 1,
  createdBy: 1,
  updatedBy: 1,
  publishedAt: null,
  createdAt: 2022-08-26T08:57:11.542Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-08-26T08:57:11.542Z
}
```

and the result i get at afterCreate hook's event is this :

```
{
  id: 34,
  first_name: 'John',
  last_name: 'from strapi local',
  email: 'member@email.test',
  phone_number: '123456',
  number_of_property_managed: '3',
  createdAt: '2022-08-26T08:57:11.542Z',
  updatedAt: '2022-08-26T08:57:11.542Z',
  publishedAt: null,
  country: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Malaysia',
    createdAt: '2022-05-11T19:23:28.047Z',
    updatedAt: '2022-05-11T19:23:28.835Z',
    publishedAt: '2022-05-11T19:23:28.815Z'
  },
  createdBy: {
    id: 1,
    ...
  },
  updatedBy: {
    id: 1,
    ...
  }
}
```

country relation appears.

Now here're the params i received from beforeCreate hook, from the REST API triggered from my FE :

```
{
  first_name: 'John',
  last_name: 'from FE local',
  email: 'member@email.test',
  phone_number: '018888888888',
  country: 1,
  number_of_property_managed: '10',
  publishedAt: 2022-08-26T08:55:02.879Z,
  createdAt: 2022-08-26T08:55:02.884Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-08-26T08:55:02.884Z
}
```

Here's the result i get at afterCreate hook's event :

```
{
  id: 33,
  first_name: 'John',
  last_name: 'from FE local',
  email: 'member@email.test',
  phone_number: '018888888888',
  number_of_property_managed: '10',
  createdAt: '2022-08-26T08:55:02.884Z',
  updatedAt: '2022-08-26T08:55:02.884Z',
  publishedAt: '2022-08-26T08:55:02.879Z'
}
```

country is somehow not loaded.

**WHAT I NEED :**
I need to access the relation datas after i triggered the data creation from the REST API.

**NOTE :**
I've searched through google for similar issues but what i've found are a bit different. Most of them doesn't mention whether the issue is when they're adding the data from the Strapi admin page, or using the REST API, so i'm guessing those are old issues that happened when they added data from the admin page (which were mentioned to be fixed at version 3.0.0).

The Strapi that i use right now is 4.1.8

Comment: I'm having the exact problem, do you know how you fixed it?